Solving second order constant coefficient differential equation with complex parameter
For context, I'm trying to solve the time-independent Schrodinger equation for an imaginary potential, that is,
$$
V = iV_0, 0 \leq x \leq 2L
$$
The equation is:
$$
\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} = -\frac{2m(E_n - iV_0)}{\hbar^2} \psi
$$
where $V_0, m, \hbar$ are real parameters.
I've made a genuine attempt to solve it, by solving with boundary conditions $\psi(0) = 0, \psi(2L) = 0$, and I've got the following as my solution:
$$
\psi(x) = Be^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)
$$
Here, B is just a normalisation constant and that doesn't matter too much.
$$
\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \sqrt{E_n^2+V_0^2}} \cos(\frac{1}{2}\theta)
$$
$$
\beta = \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \sqrt{E_n^2+V_0^2}} \sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta)
$$
$$\theta = \pi-\arctan(\frac{V_0}{E_n})$$
Is this right? I've made an attempt at solving for $E_n$, but only got upto this equation which I can't solve:
$$\frac{4m^2}{\hbar^4}(E_n^2+V_0^2) \sin^4(\frac{1}{2}\theta) = \frac{n^4\pi^4}{8L^4}$$

Remember your trig identities: $2\sin^2(\phi/2) = 1 - \cos \phi$ and $\cos(\arctan a) = 1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

As usual, the soution for $\psi''(x) = a\psi(x)$ is $A e^{\sqrt{a} x}+B e^{-\sqrt{a} x}$.  This holds even if $a$ is a complex constant.  And of course $A,B$ are arbitrary complex numbers.  I think we cannot (in general) expect it to have a zero at a real number $2L$; perhaps a zero is some complex number?  [For example, if $a<0$, we get solutions $\sinh$ and $\cosh$.]

Your boundary conditions suggest this is intended to be the infinite square well. That is, $V = \infty$ outside of $[0, 2L]$. If this is intended as the finite square well, then your boundary conditions are $\psi(\pm\infty) = 0$ and the conditions at $0$ and $2L$ are instead continuity conditions.

This answer assumes the potential is intended as an infinite square well, since that's what the boundary conditions you're using suggest.
Using $2\sin^2(\theta/2) = 1 - \cos\theta$, we can write the boundary condition $2\beta L = n\pi$ as
$$
\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{4L^2m} = \sqrt{E_n^2 + V_0^2}(1 - \cos\theta).
$$
Now, what is $\cos\theta$? Using $\cos(\tan^{-1}a) = 1/\sqrt{1+a^2}$, we have $\cos\theta = - E_n/\sqrt{E_n^2 + V_0^2}$, and so
$$
\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{4L^2m} =  \sqrt{E_n^2 + V_0^2} + E_n.
$$
This algebraic equation $u + \sqrt{1+u^2} = R$ has the real solution $u = (R-R^{-1})/2$ for $R > 0$. This allows us to solve the previous for $E_n$, giving
$$
E_n = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{4L^2m} - \frac{4L^2mV_0^2}{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}\right) = E_{0n}\left(1 - \frac{V_0^2}{E_{0n}^2}\right),
$$
where $E_{0n}$ are the energy levels for the infinite square well with $V_0 = 0$.

Hey, thanks a lot. This fully answers my question. The problem is meant to illustrate what can happen with a complex potential, and the energy spectrum of a hamiltonian under a complex potential. In this case, a complex valued infinite square will. This answer seems right, because we can recover the usual ISW energy spectrum if we set V0 = 0
